# 3 Monitors on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: amd-graphics

I have one Ati Radeon 4200 on my mohterboard, and one Ati Radeon 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series graphics card with a dual VGA out. I've installed fglrx from the repositories.  When the computer starts the Ubuntu logo appears on the motherboard screen, then the two screens connected to the graphics cards launch the desktop, the motherboard screen just says "ubuntu", with the red dots below it.

How can i configure the machine to use all three screens?

Thanks,
       Rob Brew.